# print password with special character in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, passwords

I need to print this password in script :

```
PASS="$database$"
echo "sqlcmd  -U system -P $PASS -S dbtest ">> exec.bat
```

but when I execute the script, I have thi result:

```
echo "sqlcmd  -U system -P **$** -S dbtest ">> exec.bat
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use single quotes in the assignment:

```
PASS='$database$'
```

Currently, `$database` is being interpreted as the value of a variable, because of the double quotes.

Comment: No problem. If your problem is solved, don't forget to accept my answer by clicking on the check mark ✓ next to it. Thanks.